# Update with result of GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know enough SQL to write basic `SELECT` and `UPDATE`s. I'm struggling with `JOIN`s

I want to update the 'county' field in a crime table. I am using a zip_xref table that will give me the county names. The issue is that several hundred cities are in multiple counties, and I want to update the table with the most prevalent county, so my sub-query must have a way to rank the counties by size.

I've written this to find the county names ranked by the number of zip codes in each county.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountyName AS counties, COUNT(*) AS numZips  
FROM Zip_XRef WHERE (CityName = 'Aurora') AND (StateName = 'Colorado')  
GROUP BY CountyName ORDER BY numZips DESC
```

I know this UPDATE doesn't work, it's just the idea.

```
UPDATE crime_table_08 AS c  
SET county =   
    (SELECT TOP 1 DISTINCT CountyName, COUNT(*) AS numZips 
    FROM Zip_XRef AS z 
    WHERE RTRIM(z.StateName) = RTRIM(c.State) AND RTRIM(z.CityName) = RTRIM(c.city)
    GROUP BY CountyName ORDER BY numZips DESC
    )
```

I'm thinking that I'll need to create a temporary table, and then call it to update c, and I can't quite get my head around the logic. Any help greatly appreciated.

OR, Does anyone think there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE c 
SET county =   t.CountyName
FROM crime_table_08 AS c  
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP (1) CountyName
   FROM (
       SELECT CountyName, COUNT(*) as cnt
       FROM Zip_XRef AS z 
       WHERE RTRIM(z.StateName) = RTRIM(c.State) AND RTRIM(z.CityName) = RTRIM(c.city)
       GROUP BY CountyName)
   ) AS s
   ORDER BY cnt DESC) as t;
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I am on WIN Server 2003/SQL 2000.  What would it look like as an inner join?

Comment: You cannot have correlated inner joins (ie. a join that has a WHERE clause that references fields in the `c` alias). You can use subqueries, but it will get really really messy quick. I'll try to post a solution later when I get a minute to look at it.

Comment: It would seam that a temporary table would work, like so:  
  UPDATE crime_table_08
  SET County = (
   SELECT TOP 1 county
   FROM 
    (CREATE TABLE countyTemp (
     county VARCHAR(255),
     numZips int IDENTITY (1, 1) 
     )
    INSERT INTO countyTemp (county, numZips)
     SELECT CountyName, COUNT(*) as cnt
             FROM Zip_XRef AS z, crime_table_08 AS c
             WHERE RTRIM(z.StateName) = RTRIM(c.State) AND RTRIM(z.CityName) = RTRIM(c.city)
             GROUP BY CountyName
    )
   )

  But I am getting errors: near 'CREATE' and Line 12 near ')'